# Failing to have visible features in ArcMap 10.5

Tags: arcmap, labeling, export, resolution, font

[image]How do I increase visibility of my map? Feature labels are too tiny and features are too blurred. I am using ArcMap 10.5. I tried to change the resolution to 3000 dpi but still didn't work out. I also tried to increase the layout view.

Comment: can you provide an example (screenshot?)

Comment: Are you using your own data or some basemap from a web-service ? Also are your data vector or raster ? What are your settings (scale, page size, did you set a reference scale, ...) Please give more detail by editing your question. (and yes a screenshot would be nice)

Comment: im using my own data

Comment: @Mapperz I am failing to see the option to add a file

Comment: @SteveSparrow-smith https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/18/new-image-upload-support/#:~:text=Yes%2C%20that%20means%20adding%20a,there%E2%80%A6&text=%2DFounder%20(Former)-,Thanks%20to%20our%20good%20friends%20at%20imgur.com%2C%20we%20now,all%20Stack%20Exchange%20network%20websites.